# Issue with divisors finding function. Expected is <System.Int32[2]>

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have an issue with the following one :

Create a function named divisors/Divisors that takes an integer and returns an array with all of the integer's divisors(except for 1 and the number itself). If the number is prime return the string '(integer) is prime' (null in C#) (use Either String a in Haskell and Result, String> in Rust).

My code:

```
static int[] divisors(int a)
    {
        int[] array = new int[a];
        int x = 0;


        for( int i =2; i<a; i++)
        {

            if(a % i == 0)
            {
                array[x] = i;
                x++;
            }

        }

        if(array.Length == 0)
        {

            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return array;
        }

    }
```

When I try to run it, it throws :

```
 "Expected is <System.Int32[2]>, actual is <System.Int32[15]>
  Values differ at index [2]
  Extra:    < 0, 0, 0... >"
```

Not sure what to do with this one.
I'd really appreciate some help.

The sollution :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Kata
{
  public static int[] Divisors(int n)
  {         
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                {
                    numbers.Add (i);

                }
            }
            if (numbers.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                int[] array = new int[numbers.Count];
                array =numbers.ToArray();
                return array;    
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You array is the wrong size. Use a `List<int>`, add values that meet the criteria, `return yourList.ToArray()`

Comment: A simple solution would be to copy your array into a new one with just the right size, just before returning it

Comment: Also, think about this: if you are looking for all divisors of `6` except the number itself, why are you checking up to `5`? And if it were the divisors of `8`, why check up to `7`. There is a number past which you can't find anymore divisors, can you figure out which one?

Comment: Thank you! Managed to fix using a list.

Comment: @InBetween I guess you will never go higher than the half of the number which you're looking the divisors for.

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Comment: @InBetween But I guess it's only half of the answer, how about the rest of the divisors ? I mean for example let's take 50:

You've 2,5,10,25 (excluding 1 & 50), we've established that it's pointless to search after 50/2, but what about the rest? Like all the numbers between 10 to 25 ?

Comment: Can you give me a number larger that 25 that divides 50? Or a number larger than 50 that divides 100? The smallest possible divisor is 2, so the largest possible divisor can't be bigger than a/2.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get that error with your code; however, your function will not return null because you have determined the Length of your array as a. So the length will never be zero. You get all those zeros because value types initialize for you. Your int array filled up with zeros. I think this excercise should prove to you that a different collection type would be more suited to data that needs to be dynamicly resized but if you are required to stick to arrays, here is some code that does.

```
static int[] divisors(int a)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int[] array = new int[x];
            for (int i = 2; i < a; i++)
            {
                if (a % i == 0)
                {
                    x++;
                    Array.Resize<int>(ref array, x);
                    array[x-1] = i;
                }
            }
            if (array.Length == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return array;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int b = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int[] a = divisors(b);
            if (a == null)
                MessageBox.Show($"{b} is a prime number.");
            else
            { 
                foreach (int x in a)
                {
                    Debug.Print(x.ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
```